# Pandas forward fill with maximum until position

Tags: pandas

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([3,1,2,5,2], columns=['Var'], index=pd.date_range('2017-01-01',periods=5))
            Var
2017-01-01    3
2017-01-02    1
2017-01-03    2
2017-01-04    5
2017-01-05    2
```

And i want to create a new column with the maximum value until time period like this:

```
            Var   MaxVar
2017-01-01    3     3
2017-01-02    1     3
2017-01-03    2     3
2017-01-04    5     5
2017-01-05    2     5
```

Is this possible with pandas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [Series.cummax()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cummax.html) method:

```
In [146]: df['MaxVar'] = df.Var.cummax()

In [147]: df
Out[147]:
            Var  MaxVar
2017-01-01    3       3
2017-01-02    1       3
2017-01-03    2       3
2017-01-04    5       5
2017-01-05    2       5
```